# How can I display item's details from a recyclerview when the item is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently making an app that displays Items using RecyclerView. I want to display the details of the each item once the user has clicked on it. I have managed to setup the onclicklistener, however I am stuck on the part of displaying data of each Item once the user clicks on it. Is there any one with an example of how I can achieve this? or How solve this problem?

Comment: Check out this example http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After handling `RecyclerView's` items, you can use something like this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainRecyclerDetails.class);

            String getrec = feedItem.getTitle();
            i.putExtra("title", getrec);
            String getthumb = feedItem.getThumbnail();
            i.putExtra("Thumbnail", getthumb);
            String geturl = feedItem.getUrl();
            i.putExtra("url", geturl);
            String getTags = feedItem.getTags();
            i.putExtra("tags", getTags);

            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
```

I was trying to achieve this with getting the data's from server and just send them into `DetailsActivity` for each item.Here is the `DetailActivity` for each items:

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String title = extra.getString("title");
        TextView txtitem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtitemdetailstitle);
        txtitem.setText(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        // for Title

        Bundle extraimage = getIntent().getExtras();
        String image = extraimage.getString("thumbnail");
        ImageView imgdetailstitle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnaildetails);
        imgdetailstitle.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(image));

        // For thumbnail

        Bundle extradate = getIntent().getExtras();
        String date = extradate.getString("date");
        TextView txtdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        txtdate.setText(date);
        // for Date

        Bundle extratags = getIntent().getExtras();
        String tags = extratags.getString("tags");
        TextView txttags = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttags);
        txttags.setText(tags);
        // for Tags
```